# Can you make sub-panels in customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

I see a lot of posts about this, they all suggest some tricky ways and they say it's not possible out of the box.

But those are old posts, can anyone confirm if wp core can't handle this yet as it does with sections?

example of one of those posts:
[Theme Customizer : how to create multiple-level panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199427/theme-customizer-how-to-create-multiple-level-panel?rq=1)

Comment: I can confirm that WP Core can't handle nested panels & sections. The post you linked to is still the only way to accomplish this. Yes there are lots of posts out there on how to do this but they are pretty much all variations of that one.

Comment: +1 As far as I am aware, nothing has changed since that question was posted. Personally, I feel that if you need that many levels, then your theme is too complex. But that’s just me.

Comment: I have around 120 settings and I want to organize this, that's all.. Thanks, guys, this is my first time-disappointment from wp : ( but oh well : )